# Rails CircleCI ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, circleci

Anyone had some similar issue? - I have a project where I need to setup CircleCI with mysql db, but i receive such error:
bundle exec rails db:create db:schema:load --trace

```
rails aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes
```

I tried a tons of recommendation such as to add to Gemfile execjs and therubyracer gem but it didn't help.
Here is my config file:

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  default:
    working_directory: ~/Desktop/car_portal
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.7.0
        environment:
          BUNDLE_JOBS: 3
          BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
          BUNDLE_RETRY: 3
          BUNDLER_VERSION: 2.1.2
          RAILS_ENV: test
          DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
          DB_USERNAME: root
          DB_PASSWORD: ''
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.7.29
        command: [--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password]
        environment:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true'
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
          MYSQL_DATABASE: car_portal_test
          MYSQL_USER: root

commands:
  configure_bundler:
    description: Configure bundler
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Configure bundler
          command: |
            echo 'export BUNDLER_VERSION=$(cat Gemfile.lock | tail -1 | tr -d " ")' >> $BASH_ENV
            source $BASH_ENV
            gem install bundler

jobs:
  build:
    executor: default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - car_portal-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - car_portal-
      - configure_bundler
      - run:
          name: Install bundle
          command: bundle install
      - run:
          name: Wait for DB
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://127.0.0.1:3306 -timeout 1m
      - run:
          name: Setup DB
          command: bundle exec rails db:create db:schema:load --trace
      - run:
          name: RSpec
          command: |
            bundle exec rspec --profile 10 \
                              --format progress
      - store_artifacts:
          path: coverage
      - save_cache:
          key: car_portal-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/Desktop
          paths:
            - ./Desktop/car_portal

workflows:
  version: 2
  integration:
    jobs:
      - build
```

And here is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV['CAR_PORTAL_DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['CAR_PORTAL_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['CAR_PORTAL_DB_SCHEMA'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['CAR_PORTAL_TEST_DB_SCHEMA'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: car_portal_production
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['CAR_PORTAL_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I have rails 6.0.4.4 installed. Maybe I could use before_script (as gitlab CI uses) in CircleCI to install nodejs related packages?

Comment: Which Docker version are you running? `docker -v`

Comment: @dario Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I had the same problem with version 18 but it was solved after upgrading to 20. Kinda weird tbh.

Comment: @dario No, I did not.

Comment: try remplace `image: circleci/ruby:2.7.0` by `image: cimg/ruby:2.7.0-node`